# CS-Studio 4.4.1 + Tango Controls on Debian 10 machine: GUI fails with SWTException and NoClassDefFoundError, possibly deprecated Corba classes

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11, corba, java-module

So...I am trying to use CSS for building GUIs to control Tango devices in a Linux server. When running a very simple GUI (just reading voltages from the instrument and updating on a display), the GUI runs, but the process variables are 'disconnected', even though the syntax is correct.

The console gives me the following errors when starting the GUI:

```
SEVERE [Thread 1] org.csstudio.logging.PluginLogListener (logging) - Unhandled event loop exception
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/UserException)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4491)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4406)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3794)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3433)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/UserException
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:272)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.omg.CORBA.UserException cannot be found by tangorb-jacorbfree_9.2.2
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 62 more
```

And the following errors when closing the GUI window:

```
SEVERE [Thread 1] org.csstudio.logging.PluginLogListener (logging) - Error disposing widget for : org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.PartImpl OPI View
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.csstudio.opibuilder.editparts.AbstractBaseEditPart.deactivate(AbstractBaseEditPart.java:315)
    at org.csstudio.opibuilder.editparts.AbstractContainerEditpart.deactivate(AbstractContainerEditpart.java:291)
    at org.csstudio.opibuilder.editparts.DisplayEditpart.deactivate(DisplayEditpart.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.deactivate(AbstractEditPart.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.deactivate(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.AbstractEditPartViewer.unhookControl(AbstractEditPartViewer.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.GraphicalViewerImpl.unhookControl(GraphicalViewerImpl.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.AbstractEditPartViewer.setControl(AbstractEditPartViewer.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.AbstractEditPartViewer.handleDispose(AbstractEditPartViewer.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.GraphicalViewerImpl.handleDispose(GraphicalViewerImpl.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.AbstractEditPartViewer$2.widgetDisposed(AbstractEditPartViewer.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1329)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1138)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3814)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1376)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3814)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1376)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3814)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.disposeWidget(SWTPartRenderer.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.disposeWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$1(PartRenderingEngine.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$3.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:837)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    ...
```

When I google about it, (I believe) I could already rule out some common scenarios:

1. Problem with gtk 3: my cs-studio ini file has this line forcing to use gtk 2.
2. Wrong java class path: checking the installation details/configurations of CSS, the java class path is set correctly.

Now, the two following cases may be more likely:

3. Deprecated CORBA classes after JDK 8 (released 2012): it seems after JDK 8 some corba class definitions were removed, maybe affecting any calls of dependencies. Well, that could be possible, but these GUIs have been developed and used after 2018 in JDK 11 (though on a Windows machine with local instruments, and now I am trying on remote tango servers on a Debian 10 machine). Why should it be still calling deprecated corba classes at this point?
4. Missing *.jar files related to SWT in the plug-ins folder: when checking for these files, I just find **org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.104.2.v20160212-1350.jar** and **org.eclipse.swt_3.104.2.v20160212-1350.jar**. However (from: [Eclipse FAQ](https://eclipse.org/swt/faq.php)):

> Q: Why do I get the error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/internal/XXX/OS."?
> A: On some platforms such as GTK, SWT is broken into multiple jars. Therefore, you must ensure that all required jars are on the classpath. The required jars are:
>
> ```
>    swt.jar (all platforms)
>    swt-pi.jar (some platforms like GTK and Carbon)
>    swt-mozilla.jar (for Browser widget on GTK and Motif)
>    swt-gtk.jar (on Linux Motif)
> ```

So far I haven't found out how to download these files. Anyone?
Anyway, could this be it? Did anyone experience any of these issues?

I appreciate any help.

Cheers!

Comment: The stack trace shows all the necessary SWT code is present, so it is not that. The jars need for SWT are different in an Eclipse RCP from a standalone SWT app.

Comment: Thanks, Greg! So probably there are still some dependencies of absent corba classes, which I have to find out how to implement under jdk 11 (?) or else get rid of..